# Odoo: Hide HTTP Long polling log

Tags: odoo

When the Odoo server is launched, it regulary process some Long Polling Request which are logged like this:

```
2018-08-22 19:13:31,231 22813 INFO my_data_base werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2018 19:13:31] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I'm wondering if a way exists to hide them because it's annoying when you are debugging with `pdb` for example.

I know I could set the flag `--log-handler` to `:WARNING` level but it makes the server really quiet and I don't like that. There is few log levels: `NOTSET`, `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARNING`, `ERROR` and `CRITICAL`.

Any help would be appreciate

Comment: You can set the logging level by using the `--log-handler` parameter, just change the logging level of the module emitting the message

Answer (score 0):

Set `log_handler = *:DEBUG,werkzeug:CRITICAL`

That way you can see only the critical messages coming from werkzeug and debug from everywhere else, change this according to your needs.